# Change focus in MapTool ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, .net, arcgis-pro-sdk, sdk

I have a requirement in ArcGIS Pro which is if something is selected and tool is opened with that selected data then the blue line  around the tool (shown in attached image) should be visible. And if nothing is selected in the map then there should not be blue line around the tool. I think we can replicate this if u open the tool and u click on the tool then this line comes across the tool makes the focus on the tool and then if you will click on the map then blue line disappears from the tool and focus is now on the map.

But now we need to implement something like this based on selection. That's why if any selection focus should be on the tool which can be shown using blue line around the tool. If no selection then no blue line and focus should be on the map.

[image: ToolWithBlueLine]

How can I do this?